# what does "showing the fly the way out of the fly-bottle" literally means?

Tags: expressions, idioms, terminology, logic, syntactic-analysis

I saw this expression:

"the aim of the activity is "to show the **fly** the way out of the **fly-bottle**". "

(It is connected with this other expression: "I don't know my way about".)

I grasped the general sense of the expression but I don't understand clearly how it is formed, i.e. it's logical analysis (e.g, is "fly" a noun in this case?).

- Which are the logical analysis and the literal meaning of the expression "to show the fly the way out ot the fly-bottle"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wittgenstein thought that the pursuit of philosophy in its traditional sense is pointless. Philosophers who scoured far and wide for a structured logical form applicable to everything were deluded and wasting their time, much like a fly who constantly tries to escape a transparent bottle by banging against the side. Wittgenstein saw it as his job to show these tenacious philosophers out of the top of the fly-bottle and to see philosophy for what it really is – a futile attempt to find an all-encompassing logical form of thought behind the mess that is ordinary language…

Comment: And if you've ever actually seen a fly in a bottle, they are pretty much incapable of finding their way out, and will generally resist your attempts to assist them.